# How to display the current title from a json request

Tags: javascript, json, while-loop, brightcove

I'm looking to get a title of the specific item that is being selected on my page:

```
function response(jsonData) {
    var items = jsonData["items"];
    var tDiv = document.getElementById("dynamicVideos");
    var uDiv = document.getElementById("videoInfo");
    var i=0;        

    while (i<items.length) {        

        var str = "";
        str += '<div class="tvVideo">';
        str += '<div class="thumb" onClick="playTitleFromList(' + items[i].id + ')"><img src="' + items[i].thumbnailURL + '"/></div>';
        str += '<p class="vidTitle">' + items[i].name + ' (' + formatTime(items[i].length) + ')'+ '</p>';
        str += '<p class="vidDescription">' + items[i].shortDescription + '</p>';
        str += '</div>';

        tDiv.innerHTML += str;

        i++;
    }

    var str2 = "";
    str2 += '<div class="videoTitle">';
    str2 += '<h3 id="videoTitle">' + items[0].name + '</h3>';
    str2 += '</div><!-- Video Title -->';
    str2 += '<div class="videoDescription">';
    str2 += '<p id="videoDescription">' + items[0].longDescription + '</p>';
    str2 += '</div><!-- Video Description -->';
    str2 += '<div class="divide"></div>';
    str2 += '<div id="videoDonate"></div>';
    str2 += '<div id="videoTAF"></div>';
    str2 += '<div id="videoTime"></div>';

    uDiv.innerHTML += str2;
}
```

The bottom portion of the code should display the video selected's info as the top code block returns the list of video.

Comment: What is "selected video"? Is that something that is returned in the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "selected" you mean the last item you've clicked, you'll need to add code to `playTitleFromList` to populate your page with the data.  That function will need access to the same data that's in `jsonData` so it has the values it needs.  That function is currently passed the ID that needs to be looked up; alternately, you could change the code so that `i` is passed as the parameter rather than the `id` so that you can just access the item in the array.

Comment: So are you saying that this function playTitleFromList needs to be outside of function response?

Comment: Since you're referencing it as part of an `onclick` attribute, it will need to be available in the global scope.  Otherwise, you'll need to attach the click handler differently.